# Why JSONObject.get("name") returns null?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to access an element in one of my JSONObject. I am using 
json-simple-1.1.1.jar. I can access the first "course" like you see in the code. The problem is, I cannot access the elements like "CourseNo" or "SubjectName".

My JSON data is:

```
[
    {
        Course: {
            SubjectName: "ACCT",
            CourseNo: "201",
            SectionNo: "A",
            Instructors: [
                {
                    Name: "AYLÄ°N SUNA",
                    Surname: "Ã–ZKAYA",
                    IsPrimary: true
}
],
Schedule: [
{
StartDate: "/Date(1347829200000)/",
FinishDate: "/Date(1356645600000)/",
MeetingTime: [
{  
     .... and it goes like that.
```

This is just the first element of course array ( course[0] ). I can reach it but not it's elements like CourseNo..

Here is my simple code:

```
public class CourseQuerySystem {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("CoursesOffered.json");
        JSONArray courseData = (JSONArray)JSONValue.parse(reader);
        JSONObject firstCourse = (JSONObject)courseData.get(0);  // first course
        System.out.println(firstCourse); // it works 

        String courseNo = (String) firstCourse.get("CourseNo");
        System.out.println(courseNo); // returns NULL

        boolean contains = firstCourse.containsKey("CourseNo");
        System.out.println(contains);  // returns false

    }
}
```

So, normally string courseNo should be equal to "201" but it returns null.
And boolean contains should be true but it's not.

My output:

```
{"Course":{"Instructors":[{"IsPrimary":true,"Surname":"ÖZKAYA","Name":"AYLİN
SUNA"}],"SubjectName":"ACCT","Schedule": .... (it goes.. this is true)
null 
false
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Note the fixed indentation in the first bit. To get at name, it's `decoded_json[0].course.instructors[0].name`

Comment: In your JSON, you have an array of objects. Each of these objects has a Course object within it, then each course object has the property you require. So, loop through each of the objects in the array, get the course object, then the property you require. Look at the output of first course. You can see that it contains a course object, so you need to go one level deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to call `get()` on the `Course` object in your JSON. Look at your JSON carefully and you'll see what I mean.

```
public class CourseQuerySystem {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("CoursesOffered.json");
        JSONArray courseData = (JSONArray)JSONValue.parse(reader);
        JSONObject firstCourse = (JSONObject)courseData.get(0);  // first course
        System.out.println(firstCourse); // it works 

        String courseNo = (String) firstCourse.get.get("Course").get("CourseNo");
        System.out.println(courseNo); // Should work
    }
}
```

Note that in these type of scenarios, good use of your debugger should help you figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `JSONObject` accessed via the `Course` key that you must drill into before you can get to `CourseNo`.